# Redirecting output and errors

Tags: shell

Hello I am trying to delete all files in a directory if they have 'm' in their names and redirect the deleted ones in a file ANSWER and if there are errors in file ERRORS.So I have created these 2 files and I tried to execute everything at once here is my code :

```
rm  $ (ls | grep 'm' > ANSWER 2>ERROR)
```

however I get th error that rm is missing operand (I do have files that have m in their name in the current directory)

Answer (score 0):

In your inner command all of the output is redirected to the ANSWER file and nothing is left for rm.  You can see this if you evaluate

`ls | grep 'm' > ANSWER 2>ERROR`

nothing will be printed to the screen. To get it to work in one command you can try

`rm  $(ls | grep 'm' > >(tee ANSWER) 2>ERROR)`

with `tee` writing to standard output and the ANSWER file